# Force order of painting, in non-stacked area chart

Tags: vega-lite

While working with Vega Lite, I'm unable to force the same order for painting non-stacked areas.

For example, see what happens here:

[image]

In the rows picture above, I expect light-blue to always be behind dark-blue. However this is not true for the 3rd, 4th, and 6th row.

I've tried several combinations of order, sort, and zrank — with no success. Any idea on how to force this?

See the sample [full viz in the editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgB3RgBMW2MAFYADMdW5kjavgPSzGyDvR5MOYJFYAnMQcj4iJORMsHgMzGzsrLDInvDKeMhKoXGopABmiNxpaeikhgCc8ABMABw6yMZFAOzw0kXw6OgAjGnsAGxt7IYlafDIVWlVxjqknuiapOzIacjsRejSVeVpbWkAzG06+Wv5hoOG8E3Sa2tpx-lti1XoRWmkCSF08LAUkAC+6hAQkOzcrEo6WDYSBpMRRRBqByEdA6HSMJTUbD2b6waHweGIrBNT5QDCeADW2FAXygeAAnoRkMD0J5kJgcd9uGjmGSkXQqhoPg5EnE4QiiRpvgAPAUk75pRjIMQ6YFxJRUTzUZA6AD6TgSkLFpIpVKwkCU3FQ8PQPgZX0g6CFjCBWGJWtJzDEusgABVGKgqYKvm8vVySZBWbaveLJdLgWM8DwVVkVRgRWbvuTKcCAI6sdBJZjORhUTVii1Wm12rWQSN4J3AvMlsToKZiG05evIYNgP35kLoeCErCN6IgX1myBxMTcTyi-MSqUyvVkuljhPa5N6g1GpQmqvmhAm3XF-38NDO6GMWkyrUtn1n30gQeebiacf+ydhvVxf54TxklVrj0bxM64Ersapotn4dLlGOQb2lANZ1gAYvEADKjAAF66vkLYQOYkAwVKACCCIVlgazGP2Wptnuo54A++ZMsCca-uaT7TpAEZRuUCCJFRC6Mp44HAuxfQAhikDnleEA+j6IBAA) — I can't get India, Israel, or Japan to display the dark-blue area on top of the light-blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is currently a way to control the z order of area charts from the chart spec, but you can control it via the order of the data source: the colors are stacked in the order that they appear. For example, here in row 0, color 1 comes first, and in row 1, color 0 comes first:

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 2, "row": 0, "color": 1},
      {"x": 1, "y": 1, "row": 0, "color": 1},
      {"x": 0, "y": 1, "row": 0, "color": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 2, "row": 0, "color": 0},
      {"x": 0, "y": 2, "row": 1, "color": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 1, "row": 1, "color": 0},
      {"x": 0, "y": 1, "row": 1, "color": 1},
      {"x": 1, "y": 2, "row": 1, "color": 1}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "area",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative", "stack": false},
    "color": {"field": "color", "type": "ordinal"},
    "row": {"field": "row", "type": "ordinal"}
  },
  "height": 50
}
```

[image]

If you rearrange the rows so that color 0 appears before color 1 in both cases, the stack order on the chart will be consistent:

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 1, "row": 0, "color": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 2, "row": 0, "color": 0},
      {"x": 0, "y": 2, "row": 0, "color": 1},
      {"x": 1, "y": 1, "row": 0, "color": 1},
      {"x": 0, "y": 2, "row": 1, "color": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 1, "row": 1, "color": 0},
      {"x": 0, "y": 1, "row": 1, "color": 1},
      {"x": 1, "y": 2, "row": 1, "color": 1}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "area",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative", "stack": false},
    "color": {"field": "color", "type": "ordinal"},
    "row": {"field": "row", "type": "ordinal"}
  },
  "height": 50
}
```

[image]

If you re-order the rows your input data by year (so all 2019 entries come before all 2020 entries), the stack order should be the same in each panel.